# IOS - replacing the initial view in NavController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to revise an app I did in iOS a few months ago that uses a navigation controller.

My goal is to replace the current default view controller with a new one (which will in turn call the original view controller)

In trying to tease apart what has to happen in order to do this. I've created a new view controller and the corresponding nib, and set them up as variables in the app delegate.  In the app delegate, this is the current code which makes the call to the "old" initial view:

```
navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:questionViewController];

[window addSubview:navController.view];

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Question 1: the nib file for the main window (MainWindow.xlb) has the question view controller as an object  (as well as the navigation controller). Does it need to be there?

Question 2: what should I change to make the new view controller the default view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, you need that connection otherwise you wouldn't be able to reference `questionViewController` from the app delegate like you currently are. But if the `questionViewController` is no longer your first view controller, you should replace it with a different one.
2. Just like you already have, use

```
navController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:/*new first view controller*/];
```

Of course you'll also have to put it in the xib file and connect it to an IBOutlet so you can use it.

Comment: Thanks - a sigabort had recently answered question 1! For future reference, I added a ViewController from the object library in to the main nib, and connected it to the relevant nib using the property inspector. From there it was just a question of connecting the app delegate object to the new nib by dragging and attaching.